# Export mysql2 connection to other files node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql2

I am trying to use one connection across all the files in a node and mysql2 project.

This is what I did ->

```
// db.js

const mysql = require('mysql2')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({dbinfo})

console.log(connection) // the connection is proper

module.exports = { connection }
```

```
//server.js

const { con } = require('./db')

console.log(con) //returns undefined
```

Similar thing works if I use the mysql package instead with mysql2

Comment: Remove { } brackets in db.js file  at last statement Or write update server.js like  const {connection} =require('./db');

Comment: The first one didnt work, the second one did. But then I am not able to query the database, it gives connection.query is not a function

Comment: const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
  // create the connection
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});     please match this code

Comment: i tried to do this but the problem is the await part should be called from an async function, so if I put the connection in an async function and export the function or return value, i will have to call the exported function inside async in app,js and every other file, otherwise it returns promise or undefined